# How to prevent texture getting automatically linked to the Displacement Modifyer?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement

I have a Displacement Modifyer that is linked to a cloud texture.

Now I wanted to create a new (different) Cloud Texture in the Texture Properties and use this one as a Brush.
But as soon as I make any new Texture or any alterations in the Texture Properties, the Texture in the Displacement Modifyer automatically switches to this new texture as well.

How can I arrange, that the Displacement Modifyer sticks to it's assigned texture and does not switch to whatever I am trying to setup in the Texture Properties?

I already tried Fake User, Make Single User Copy or creating new textures.

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure that you have selected the right destination on the top dropdown menu in the Texture panel?

Comment: Hey. Not quite sure what you mean. I've added some screenshots now.  If I have Texture 3 in the Texture Properties, the Displacement Modifyer switches to texture 3. If I change it to Texture 2 in the Texture Properties, the Displacement Modifyer automatically switches to Texture 2 as well. I have no idea how I can interrupt this mechanism. I actually thought Make single User copy was designed to prevent this. Many thanks for your help Moonboots.

Comment: I think I understood what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in the *Texture* panel and you want to choose a texture for your brush, you need to click on the top dropdown menu and choose *Brush* instead of *Displace*. Then in the dropdown menu below it should automatically create a new texture (you'll also see the one you've created for the *Displace* modifier if you ever want to select it but it's not the case here).

[image]

Comment: I can't wait for the legacy texture-system to go. I guess it must have tendrils everywhere...

Comment: @ Robin Betts, what will it be replaced with? I hope they won't change the system, it takes so long to understand  ^^